# Using variables in JSP that have been passed from a servlet?

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to use an xml string in a JSP that I've passed from a servlet. The variable passes fine. I use the code:

```
request.setAttribute("xml",xmlDoc_str2);
request.getRequestDispatcher("./jsp/pdirdetail.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

However, I'm not sure how to use it on the jsp end. I need to parse it and read it in the JSP. I'm using the code:

```
<%=request.getAttribute("xml") %>
<%
        try{
            DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(${xml}));
        }
        catch(Exception e){}

    %>
```

It apparently doesn't like the way I'm referencing the variable. I'm not sure if there's another way to do this or if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with ***[XML Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakq.html)*** that provides an easy notation for specifying and selecting parts of an XML document.

The problem is at below line. You can't mix JSTL inside Scriptlet.

```
new StringReader(${xml})
```

Always [try to avoid *Scriptlet*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/217324) instead use [JSP Standard Tag Library](https://jstl.java.net) or JSP Expression Language.

---

#### Sample code using XML Tag Library:

XML:

```
<books>
<book>
  <name>Padam History</name>
  <author>ZARA</author>
  <price>100</price>
</book>
<book>
  <name>Great Mistry</name>
  <author>NUHA</author>
  <price>2000</price>
</book>
</books>
```

Servlet:

```
// assign the XML in xmlDoc_str2 and set it as request attribute
request.setAttribute("xml",xmlDoc_str2);
request.getRequestDispatcher("./jsp/pdirdetail.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>

<html>
<head>
  <title>JSTL x:parse Tags</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Books Info:</h3>

<x:parse xml="${xml}" var="output"/>
<b>The title of the first book is</b>: 
<x:out select="$output/books/book[1]/name" />
<br>
<b>The price of the second book</b>: 
<x:out select="$output/books/book[2]/price" />

</body>
</html>
```

output:

```
Books Info:
The title of the first book is:Padam History
The price of the second book: 2000
```

Comment: Just to note: the problems are that OP's trying to use Expression Language inside scriptlet, which won't work ever.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but scriplet is also not the correct way. Let me address the actual issue as well.

Comment: I made a change to my question. I'm using getAttribute instead of getParameter.

Comment: How would I do that if I was using a variable that was taken from a servlet instead of a url location? Is that possible?

Comment: I have edited in my post. Simply store the xml string as request attribute and use EL `${xml}` to access it in JSP.